# JPA-Hibernate behaviour when a Lazy child is deleted by another transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say i have a Parent class with a one to one relationship to a **Lazy** Child. Let's say there are two transactions(querying the same parent-child) running: One just updates or maybe gets the whole thing while the other deletes the child. If the delete commits first, would the call to getChild() by the later transaction return null? Since it can't query the child anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! it will return null.
If a relation marked as LAZY then the child record will not loaded until you call it's getter method.
and then hibernate will execute a query to load it from database.
so if a transaction deletes the child record the other one will face with null value.